# Can I use existing 40 AMP breakers when the item calls for 30 AMP

Tags: electrical, water-heater, tankless

My tankless water heater stopped working and I purchased a new but slightly smaller one.  The description on the website said that it used the same wiring as my last one (3 40 AMP breakers and 8/2 AWG wires).

The instruction coming with the new unit now say it requires 3 30 AMP breakers and 10/2 wires.

Can I keep my existing 40 breakers if I am also using the 8/2 wiring?  I have read other comments that say that the person couldn't use the 30amp since the wiring was probably 10/2, but I know mine is 8/2 so I am hoping I can still use the newer and smaller heater.
Thanks

Comment: What make and model is the new water heater?

Answer (score 2):

It may be possible if the new water heater doesn't state the maximum breaker size.

If the manufacturer only states the minimum, since you are not at 150% I would hook a triple 40a to the new triple 30 water heater.

It is not Code compliant to go the other way from 3 30 with #10 to a 40 this is correct.

Comment: I was going to say something similar, but wasn't sure, so I shut up! Hoped and glad you chimed in!  I thought that was the correct answer, but wasn't sure enough to respond.

Comment: Well as long as the MFG doesn't state a maximum value that is lower, I haven’t checked 2020 code but 150% is stated some place.

Answer (score 1):

I would change the breakers. The instructions are part of the NRTL Listing. And the NEC says:

> **NEC 110.3(B) Installation and Use** Listed and Labelled equipment shall be installed and used in accordance with any instructions
> included in the listing or labelling.

Breakers are cheap.